# Convert a cURL request to http_request in a Chef Recipe

Tags: curl, sonarqube, chef-infra, chef-recipe

Can someone help how I can convert the following `cURL` request to a `http_request`.

```
curl -X POST -u admin:admin -F backup=@'/tmp/backup2.xml' -v #{sonarqube_rest_uri}/qualityprofiles/restore
```

I have the backup2.xml present in my Vagrant box's /tmp folder. I can send the request by writing a bash script, but I would like a cleaner approach with the `http_request` resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
http_request 'Post backup xml' do
  headers ({
    'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data',
    'AUTHORIZATION' => "Basic #{Base64.encode64('admin:admin')}"
  })
  action :post
  url "#{sonarqube_rest_uri}/qualityprofiles/restore"
  message ::File.read("/tmp/backup2.xml")
end
```

The [`-F`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-F) flag indicates you are need the `multipart/form-data` header. You also need the authorization header for `-u admin:admin`, which the Chef docs have a good [example](https://docs.chef.io/resource_http_request.html#examples) of. Action and url are pretty straight forward. Finally, read the contents of your file as the message with `::File.read`.

However a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33262830/multipart-post-with-chef-http-request-resource/33277564#33277564) regarding the `multipart/form-data` content type suggests this type of content may not work for `http_request`. However, hopefully this helps you understand how to turn a `curl` request in to a `http_request`